# Display plugin result to product list page

Tags: magento2, after-plugin

I created a plugin file for showing some extra data on product detail page. May I know how to display the result to the product list? Thanks

app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Plugin/GeoModel.php

```
<?php

namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Plugin;

use Myvendor\Mymodule\Helper\GeoLocation;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;

class GeoModel {

   public function __construct(
       GeoLocation $geoLocation
   )
   {
       $this->geoLocation=$geoLocation;
   }

   public function afterGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject, $result) {
       foreach($result as $value) {
           $value->setData("ip", $this->geoLocation->getCountryCodeByIp()) ;
       }
       return $result;

   }


}
```

Comment: Please trying to understand plugin functionality it's work for update core functionality for only public class or method. If you want to display extra data on PDP page and List page you can override the page in your custom theme and get and add your custom code.

Comment: So I should override to phtml on my custom design folder? But may I know how to add the plugin result to phtml?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? @hill2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be

```
   public function afterGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject, $result) {
     foreach($result as &$value) {
         $value->setData("ip", $this->geoLocation->getCountryCodeByIp()) ;
     }
     return $result;}
```

But I think $this->geoLocation->getCountryCodeByIp() always return same result, so u don't need call in loop and u can get it on template by helper.

Example: list.phtml

$geoHelper = $this->helper(\Myvendor\Mymodule\Helper\GeoLocation::class);
$countryCodeById = $geoHelper->geoLocation->getCountryCodeByIp();